# Audio waveform and drawing grid lines - lines drifting over time

Tags: swift, audio, grid, business-process-management, waveform

I'm creating a simple audio playback MacOS application in swift. I have a waveform drawn on the screen (using https://github.com/benoit-pereira-da-silva/SoundWaveForm) along with grid lines for each bar/measure (gray lines), and grid lines for each quarter note (red lines). See image at the end of the post.

The duration of 1 bar and the total number of bars in the audio file are calculated like so:

```
let quantify1Bar = (60000 / BPM) * 4 // Milliseconds per bar
let totalBars    = totalAudioDuration * 1000 / quantify1Bar
```

Then I'm calculating the pixel distance between grid lines:

```
let pxSpacing1Bar    = (pxTimelineWidth / totalBars) * zoomLevel
let pxSpacingQuarter = (pxTimelineWidth / totalBars) * zoomLevel
```

pxTimelineWidth is 1560 pixels

My zoomLevel variable just divides or multiplies itself when the "-" and "+" buttons are clicked (i.e. if zoomLevel is 1, you see the full duration of the audio waveform...if zoomLevel is 2, you see half of the audio length... 4 = a quarter length, etc:

```
zoomLevel = zoomLevel / 2 (zoom out)
zoomLevel = zoomLevel * 2 (zoom in)
```

I'm drawing the grid lines like this:

```
let pathBar       = NSBezierPath()
let pathQuarter   = NSBezierPath()

// Draw lines for every bar
        for i in 0...totalBarLines {
            pathBar.move(to: NSPoint(x: i * pxSpacing1Bar, y: 0))
            pathBar.line(to: NSPoint(x: i * pxSpacing1Bar, y: 100))
            pathBar.lineWidth = 1
            NSColor.darkGray.setFill()
            NSColor.darkGray.setStroke()
            pathBar.stroke()
        }

    // Draw 1/4 note lines
        for i in 0...totalQuarterLines {
            if i == 0 {
                // Do nothing - skip the first line of every bar
            } else if i % 4 != 0 {
                pathQuarter.move(to: NSPoint(x: i * pxSpacingQuarter, y: 10))
                pathQuarter.line(to: NSPoint(x: i * pxSpacingQuarter, y: 90))
                pathQuarter.lineWidth = 1
                NSColor.red.setFill()
                NSColor.red.setStroke()
                pathQuarter.stroke()
            }
        }
```

My issue is that on higher zoom levels, the grid lines have a noticeable drift even over a short period of time, and each drift is greater than the previous drift (see image). This seems simple enough, is my zoomLevel variable causing this during the grid line drawing loops?

[AudioGridLines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp0iO.png)